Proof for closed form of $f_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left[ {n \choose k} \cdot f_{k-1} \cdot f_{n-k} \right]$, $f_0 = 1$
I have a smart friend that is very good at math that likes to send me math problems (that I find difficult).
Find a closed form for the following (factorials are ok):
$$f_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left[ {n \choose k} \cdot f_{k-1} \cdot f_{n-k} \right] \\ f_0 = 1$$
Often, I can solve the problems given a few hours to think. In this case, I didn't even know how to begin, so he gave me the solution:
$$f_n = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n \cdot n!}$$
And he told me to prove algebraically that the two forms are equal. (I verified with a calculator that they are, in fact, equal).
After messing around with it for a while, I found that you can group the terms for when $k=i$ and $k=n-i+1$, like so:
$$ f_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n/2} \left[ \left( {n \choose k} + {n \choose n-k+1} \right) \cdot f_{k-1} \cdot f_{n-k} \right] $$
(This works for even values of $n$, it can be modified easily for odd values of $n$ as well).
I also found another recursive definition for $f_n$ based only on the previous term, which was fairly easy to show algebraically:
$$ f_{n+1} = \frac{(2(n+1))!}{2^{n+1} \cdot (n+1)!} = \frac{2(n+1)(2n+1)(2n)!}{2(n+1) \cdot 2^n \cdot n!} = (2n+1) \cdot f_n $$
I don't know if anything I am doing is in the right direction. I seem unable to bridge the gap as the original $f_n$ depends on so many smaller terms, while the closed form when modified is an incredibly simple recurrence.
I tried to do a proof by strong induction, but ran into a mess of a summation of products of non-trivial factorials and combinations that were seemingly unrelated.
How can I derive the closed form for $f_n$ algebraically? If possible, it would help to have the thought process for if you didn't see the solution to begin with as well.

You may try exponential generating functions. $f_n/n!$ is basically the $n$th central binomial coefficient.

Yep, exponential generating function looks right. You get $F^2(x)=\frac{F(x)-1}x,$ or spmething like that. You can solve for $F$ in terms of $x$

For a easier proof you have already $f_{n+1} = (2n+1)f_n$. Take the product of both sides $\prod$ from $n=1$ to $r-1$. You will see a telescopic pattern (and a closed form) for $f_n$.

Since for $n\geq 1$: $$\begin{align}
f_n&=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} f_{k-1} f_{n-k}\\
&= n!\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f_{k-1}}{k!} \frac{f_{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\end{align}$$
Let us define the two generating functions:
$$G(x)=\sum_{r\geq 0} f_r \frac{x^r}{r!}$$
$$F(x)= \sum_{r\geq 1} f_{r-1} \frac{x^{r}}{r!}$$
Note that $G(x)=F'(x)$ which follows via reindexing of $F(x)$.
Now the Cauchy product of $F(x)$ and $F'(x)$ power series gives:
$$\begin{align}
F(x)F'(x) &= \sum_{n\geq 0} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f_{k-1} f_{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!} x^n\\
&= \sum_{n\geq 1} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f_{k-1}}{k!}\frac{f_{n-k}}{(n-k)!} x^n \\
&= F'(x) - f_0
\end{align}$$
Therefore we have to solve the following differential equation given $F(0)=0$: $$F'(x)F(x)+f_0 = F'(x)$$ to yield
$$F(x)^2-2F(x)+2f_0x=0$$
Setting $f_0=1$ and solving gives $F(x)=1-\sqrt{1-2x}$. So $F'(x)= \frac1{\sqrt{1-2x}}$. Expanding $F'(x)$ as power series via generalized Binomial theorem gives:
$$\sum_{r\geq 0} \frac{f_r}{r!} x^r = \sum_{r \geq 0} \frac {(2r)!}{2^r (r!)^2} x^r$$
Equating coefficients gives the result, viz.
$$\boxed{f_n = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}}$$

This was a fun little problem. Although I did a little amount of back calculation from the solution itself, I like the interpretation of the solution.
We start with the given recurrence relation $$f_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n{n \choose k} \cdot f_{k-1} \cdot f_{n-k}$$ Dividing it by $n!2^n$, and defining $h_n=f_n/n!2^n$, we get \begin{align*}h_n=\frac{f_n}{n!2^n}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!n!}f_{k-1}f_{n-k}\frac1{2^n}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}\left(\frac{f_{k-1}}{(k-1)!2^{k-1}}\right)\left(\frac{f_{n-k}}{(n-k)!2^{n-k}}\right)\\&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}h_{k-1}h_{n-k}\end{align*} with $h_0=1$.
Anticipating what is to come, let us define $p_{2n}=h_n$. Then we have $$p_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}p_{2k-2}p_{2n-2k}$$ with $p_0=h_0=1$.
Now we note some results from a completely different problem. Consider a symmetric random walk on $\mathbb Z$ starting from the origin. Let $P_{2n}$ be the probability that we are again at the origin after $2n$ steps. Also let $F_{2n}$ be the probability we return to the origin for the first time after $2n$ steps (with $F_0=0$). Then standard calculations show that (for a proof of the last equation, see here) $$P_{2n}=\binom{2n}{n}\frac1{2^{2n}}$$ $$P_{2n}=\sum_{j=0}^nF_{2j}P_{2n-2j}=\sum_{j=1}^nF_{2j}P_{2n-2j}$$ $$F_{2n}=\frac1{2n}P_{2n-2}$$ Plugging the last equation in the second last, we get $$P_{2n}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1{2j}P_{2j-2}P_{2n-2j}$$ with $P_0=1$. This is exactly the same recurrence relation we had!
Thus $P_{2n}=p_{2n}=h_n$. Hence we must have $$h_n=\binom{2n}{n}\frac1{2^{2n}}$$ which finally implies $$f_n=n!2^n\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!2^n}$$

Here is a slightly different proof by way of enrichment of
$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}
= \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}
\frac{(2k-2)!}{2^{k-1} (k-1)!}
\frac{(2n-2k)!}{2^{n-k} (n-k)!}.$$
The RHS is
$$\frac{(n-1)!}{2^{n-1}}
\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} {2k-2\choose k-1}
{2n-2k\choose n-k} {n-1\choose k-1}^{-1}
\\ = \frac{n!}{2^{n-1}}
\sum_{k=1}^n {n-1\choose k-1} \frac{1}{k} {2k-2\choose k-1}
{2n-2k\choose n-k} {n-1\choose k-1}^{-1}
\\ = \frac{n!}{2^{n-1}}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} {2k-2\choose k-1}
{2n-2k\choose n-k}.$$
With the usual generating functions applied in the sum, including
Catalan numbers,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n [z^{k-1}] \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}
[z^{n-k}] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^n [z^k] \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2}
[z^{n-k}] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}.$$
Here we have included $k=0$ because the first extractor gives zero in
that case. So we have
$$[z^n] \left[ \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}
- \frac{1}{2} \right]
= \frac{1}{2} {2n\choose n}.$$
Collecting everything we find
$$\frac{n!}{2^n} \frac{(2n)!}{n! n!}
= \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$$
which is the claim.
